# NullPointerException with getText()

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtextfield

I'm trying to get text from a text field but every time I run the program I get a NullPointerException. Similar problems I've found on the internet involve the text field being redeclared as a local variable, but I can't see that I am doing that here.

The error is :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

at the line specified. Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT:

This short program demonstrates the problem

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test{

public static final Test application = new Test();
private JFrame jFrame = null;
private JPanel jContentPane = null, buttonsPanel = null, cardPanel = null, manualPanel = null, uploadPanel = null,
        defaultPanel = null;
private JPanel[] mainPanel = {getDefaultPanel(), getManualPanel(), getUploadPanel()};
private JButton manualButton = null, uploadButton = null, manualAssignButton = null;
private JTextField manualEntryField = null;
private JLabel manualLabel = null;

final static String DEFAULTPANEL = "Default";
final static String MANUALPANEL = "Manual";
final static String UPLOADPANEL = "Upload";

/**
 * Main method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            application.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Get the main application frame
 * @return JFrame
 */
private JFrame getJFrame() {
    if (jFrame == null) {
        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        // Add the main content pane
        jFrame.setContentPane(getJContentPanel());
        jFrame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {   
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {    
                closeApplication();
            }
        });
    }
    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    return jFrame;
}

/**
 * Get main content
 * @return JPanel
 */
private JPanel getJContentPanel(){
    if (jContentPane == null) {
        jContentPane = new JPanel();
        jContentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        jContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jContentPane.add(getButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jContentPane.add(getCardPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    return jContentPane;
}

private JPanel getButtonsPanel() {
    if(buttonsPanel == null){
        buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));

        manualButton = new JButton("Enter manually");
        manualButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardPanel.getLayout());
                cl.show(cardPanel, MANUALPANEL);
            }
        });

        uploadButton = new JButton("Upload file");
        uploadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardPanel.getLayout());
                cl.show(cardPanel, UPLOADPANEL);
            }
        });

        buttonsPanel.add(manualButton);
        buttonsPanel.add(uploadButton);
    }
    return buttonsPanel;
}

private JPanel getCardPanel() {
    if(cardPanel == null){
        cardPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cardPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        cardPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        cardPanel.add(mainPanel[0], DEFAULTPANEL);
        cardPanel.add(mainPanel[1], MANUALPANEL);
        cardPanel.add(mainPanel[2], UPLOADPANEL);
    }
    return cardPanel;
}

private JPanel getDefaultPanel() {
    if(defaultPanel == null){
        defaultPanel = new JPanel();
    }
    return defaultPanel;
}

private JPanel getManualPanel() {
    if(manualPanel == null){
        manualPanel = new JPanel();
        manualPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        manualEntryField = new JTextField(10);
        manualEntryField.setText("Enter code");

        manualAssignButton = new JButton("Assign");
        manualAssignButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // Here is the exception
            System.out.println(manualEntryField.getText().trim());
            }
        });

        manualLabel = new JLabel("Please enter a code and press assign");

        manualPanel.add(manualEntryField);
        manualPanel.add(manualAssignButton);
        manualPanel.add(manualLabel);

    }
    return manualPanel;
}

private JPanel getUploadPanel() {
    if(uploadPanel == null){
        uploadPanel = new JPanel();
    }
    return uploadPanel;
}

private void closeApplication() {
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: At what time do you get exception ? when button is pressed ?

Comment: You have typo in code. Button is declared as `manualButton` and assigned as `manualAssignButton`. Also I tried your code it doesn't give me any exception.

Comment: I don't think this fully demonstrates the code you are running. It works fine like this.  Your method is returning a JPanel and the JTextField is an instance variable of the class....is there anywhere else in your actual code that you are doing something with the variable?

Comment: In the program the button is declared as mmanualAssignButton, I just didn't copy it over correctly.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  (Note the code already posted is **not** an SSCCE.)

Comment: *"When trying to recreate the problem in a small test program, the error doesn't occur:"* So the question becomes:-  What is ***different*** between the working example and the failing app.?

Comment: All that was different was some other panels which don't interact with the the problem panel

Comment: *"All that was different was.."* something that broke the code.  +1 for posting an SSCCE of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at your SSCCE, I managed to solve the NPE by commenting out the redundant `Test` that was instantiated, and creating the panel array in the constructor.  E.G.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test{

//public static final Test application = new Test();
private JFrame jFrame = null;
private JPanel jContentPane = null, buttonsPanel = null, cardPanel = null, manualPanel = null, uploadPanel = null,
        defaultPanel = null;
private JPanel[] mainPanel = new JPanel[3];
private JButton manualButton = null, uploadButton = null, manualAssignButton = null;
private JTextField manualEntryField = null;
private JLabel manualLabel = null;

final static String DEFAULTPANEL = "Default";
final static String MANUALPANEL = "Manual";
final static String UPLOADPANEL = "Upload";

Test() {
    mainPanel[0] = getDefaultPanel();
    mainPanel[1] = getManualPanel();
    mainPanel[2] = getUploadPanel();
}

/**
 * Main method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Test().getJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Get the main application frame
 * @return JFrame
 */
private JFrame getJFrame() {
    if (jFrame == null) {
        jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        // Add the main content pane
        jFrame.setContentPane(getJContentPanel());
        jFrame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                closeApplication();
            }
        });
    }
    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    return jFrame;
}

/**
 * Get main content
 * @return JPanel
 */
private JPanel getJContentPanel(){
    if (jContentPane == null) {
        jContentPane = new JPanel();
        jContentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        jContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jContentPane.add(getButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jContentPane.add(getCardPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    return jContentPane;
}

private JPanel getButtonsPanel() {
    if(buttonsPanel == null){
        buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));

        manualButton = new JButton("Enter manually");
        manualButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardPanel.getLayout());
                cl.show(cardPanel, MANUALPANEL);
            }
        });

        uploadButton = new JButton("Upload file");
        uploadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardPanel.getLayout());
                cl.show(cardPanel, UPLOADPANEL);
            }
        });

        buttonsPanel.add(manualButton);
        buttonsPanel.add(uploadButton);
    }
    return buttonsPanel;
}

private JPanel getCardPanel() {
    if(cardPanel == null){
        cardPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        cardPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
        cardPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
        cardPanel.add(mainPanel[0], DEFAULTPANEL);
        cardPanel.add(mainPanel[1], MANUALPANEL);
        cardPanel.add(mainPanel[2], UPLOADPANEL);
    }
    return cardPanel;
}

private JPanel getDefaultPanel() {
    if(defaultPanel == null){
        defaultPanel = new JPanel();
    }
    return defaultPanel;
}

private JPanel getManualPanel() {
    if(manualPanel == null){
        manualPanel = new JPanel();
        manualPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        manualEntryField = new JTextField(10);
        System.out.println("creating text field");
        manualEntryField.setText("Enter code");

        manualAssignButton = new JButton("Assign");
        manualAssignButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             // Here is the exception
            System.out.println(manualEntryField);
            System.out.println(manualEntryField.getText());
            System.out.println(manualEntryField.getText().trim());
            }
        });

        manualLabel = new JLabel("Please enter a code and press assign");

        manualPanel.add(manualEntryField);
        manualPanel.add(manualAssignButton);
        manualPanel.add(manualLabel);

    }
    return manualPanel;
}

private JPanel getUploadPanel() {
    if(uploadPanel == null){
        uploadPanel = new JPanel();
    }
    return uploadPanel;
}

private void closeApplication() {
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

Note:  I cannot quite explain why the changes solved the NPE, I was just refactoring 'suspicious' code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but pasting that into my program stil results in the same error. I have posted some different code which should demonstrate the problem

Comment: @SelketDaly and before anything to check if every variables are initialized, start to debuging your code on line that generated NPE

Comment: I've solved the NPE, but cannot quite explain why it now works (or failed before).

Comment: Thanks! The test program now works, but the actual application is still throwing the error. Will have another look at it

Comment: +1, for finding another way, something fishy is happening in the code even I am trying to find that out, as to what actually is causing this thing :-)  Regards

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for your help! Turnsout I forgot to add the private JPanel[] mainPanel = new JPanel[3] line! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I did solved your query related to NullPointerException :

The problem being that you declaring your class variable :

```
JTextField manualEntryField = null;
```

Just write :

```
private JTextField manualEntryField;
```

Just remove that null thing, against it and the rest of the code is fine. Cannot say as to why it happened, but might be someone else can.

Here is your code with only that change, do try this out now :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test{

public static final Test application = new Test();
    private JFrame jFrame = null;
    private JPanel jContentPane = null, buttonsPanel = null, cardPanel = null, manualPanel = null, uploadPanel = null, defaultPanel = null;
    private JPanel[] mainPanel = {getDefaultPanel(), getManualPanel(), getUploadPanel()};
    private JButton manualButton = null, uploadButton = null, manualAssignButton = null;
    private JTextField manualEntryField;
    private JLabel manualLabel = null;

    final static String DEFAULTPANEL = "Default";
    final static String MANUALPANEL = "Manual";
    final static String UPLOADPANEL = "Upload";

    /**
     * Main method
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                application.getJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the main application frame
     * @return JFrame
     */
    private JFrame getJFrame() {
        if (jFrame == null) {
            jFrame = new JFrame();
            jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            jFrame.setResizable(false);
            // Add the main content pane
            jFrame.setContentPane(getJContentPanel());
            jFrame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {   
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {    
                    closeApplication();
                }
            });
        }
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        return jFrame;
    }

    /**
     * Get main content
     * @return JPanel
     */
    private JPanel getJContentPanel(){
        if (jContentPane == null) {
            jContentPane = new JPanel();
            jContentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
            jContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jContentPane.add(getButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jContentPane.add(getCardPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }
        return jContentPane;
    }

    private JPanel getButtonsPanel() {
        if(buttonsPanel == null){
            buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
            buttonsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
            buttonsPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));

            manualButton = new JButton("Enter manually");
            manualButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardPanel.getLayout());
                    cl.show(cardPanel, MANUALPANEL);
                }
            });

            uploadButton = new JButton("Upload file");
            uploadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cardPanel.getLayout());
                    cl.show(cardPanel, UPLOADPANEL);
                }
            });

            buttonsPanel.add(manualButton);
            buttonsPanel.add(uploadButton);
        }
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getCardPanel() {
        if(cardPanel == null){
            cardPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
            cardPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
            cardPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.gray));
            cardPanel.add(mainPanel[0], DEFAULTPANEL);
            cardPanel.add(mainPanel[1], MANUALPANEL);
            cardPanel.add(mainPanel[2], UPLOADPANEL);
        }
        return cardPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getDefaultPanel() {
        if(defaultPanel == null){
            defaultPanel = new JPanel();
        }
        return defaultPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getManualPanel() {
        if(manualPanel == null){
            manualPanel = new JPanel();
            manualPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            manualEntryField = new JTextField(10);
            manualEntryField.setText("Enter code");

            manualAssignButton = new JButton("Assign");
            manualAssignButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 // Here is the exception
                    System.out.println(manualEntryField.getText().trim());
                }
            });

            manualLabel = new JLabel("Please enter a code and press assign");

            manualPanel.add(manualEntryField);
            manualPanel.add(manualAssignButton);
            manualPanel.add(manualLabel);

        }
        return manualPanel;
    }

    private JPanel getUploadPanel() {
        if(uploadPanel == null){
            uploadPanel = new JPanel();
        }
        return uploadPanel;
    }

    private void closeApplication() {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: @SelketDaly : if you will remove that null and simply right private JTextField manualEntryField; then that error is gone :-)  Regards

Comment: @mKorbel : Sure Sure, Be my guest. That would be my pleasure, hehe.  Regards

Answer (score -2):

If textBox is empty, it's normal for this exception. Try this
if(getText().size()<1) condition or use try-catch and when you catch an exception set the value non-size string "".

Comment: It happens when I have typed into the box, as well as when the box is empty

Answer (score -2):

Are you clicking the button when your text box is empty ? If so, then u can end up with that exception when u r calling the trim() function , so see what getText() returns , before calling the trim()

Comment: No even if textbox is empty it will not throw NPE.

Comment: getText will not return null if there is no text, it will return an empty String.